# Is there a way to get all file links from a single URL?

Tags: javascript, apache, https

Say I have `example.com/a.png` which is a file, and `example.com` is the main website. In a whole, `example.com` is just a site hosting raw image files. If I didn't know the name of some files, like `b.png` which the URL could be `example.com/b.png` or `example.com/b/b.png`, how would I find that? The main page is just blank, and is hosted on a `Apache 2.4.38 server`.

Right now, I'm taking blind shots by generating a random number, and appending it with `.png`. It looks something like:

```js
https.get(`https://example.com/${randomNumber}.png`, {"User-Agent":"..."}, r => {
//...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a regular expression. It could look like this:

```js
const regExp = /^https:\/\/example.com\/(.+).png$/;

// Matches
console.log(regExp.test('https://example.com/b.png'));

// Matches
console.log(regExp.test('https://example.com/b/b.png'));

// Doesn't match because of different extension
console.log(regExp.test('https://example.com/b/b.jpg'));

/*
Usage:
https.get(/^https:\/\/example.com\/(.+).png$/, {"User-Agent":"..."}, r => {
  //...
})
*/
```